# Console warnings for non-passive scroll event handlers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm getting this console error when I use Form Select from bootstrap-vue. I'm using google chrome.

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

I'm getting this data from a api, using axios. See the code below.

```
<b-form-select v-model="selected" class="mb-3">
    <option :value="null">Select a group</option>
    <option v-for="group in groupItem" :value="group.id">
        {{group.name}}
    </option>
</b-form-select>
```

Comment: It is probably because the widget takes over scrolling behavior.

Comment: And how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's related to the new event listener options, more [here](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md) and [here](https://medium.com/@devlucky/about-passive-event-listeners-224ff620e68c)

There is a new options object that can be passed to the `addEventListener`. The passive event listeners on the page should be passed the { passive: true } option to improve scroll performance.

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handler, { passive: true });
```

The warning is only a performance recommendation, not really a major concern or issue, although performance improvements are always good.

An [issue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1858) has already been reported at the bootstrap-vue repository. You can fix it by either submitting a pull request, or waiting for someone else to do it.