# iScroll v4.2.5 - Links on Google Chrome non-clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iscroll

So I've come across an issue on one of the sites that I've had for a while and out of the blue, it just stopped working. I'm receiving an event handler error when clicking on the blog posts in my iScroll module.

**Browsers**:
*Internet Explorer*: Works OK - No problem.
*Edge*: Works OK - No problem.
*Firefox*: Works OK - No problem.
*Chrome*: Throws `Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event.` error - Links unclickable.

**What I'm using**:
`iScroll v4.2.5`

**Problem**:
Throws the `Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.` error in console - Links unclickable.

Everything worked well prior to today, so I'm not sure what could have caused it to all of a sudden stop working. It's saying that it's throwing the error from the official minimized `jQuery.js` file.

This is the library that the previous developer is using: https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll

All help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53070469/1363423

Comment: Sadly, doesn't look like this helps my problem at all.